# Compare list of arrays for overlap

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of lists of arrays of the form [a, [b, c, d]], something like

`dataset = [[1, array[1, 2, 3, 4]], [0.5, array[2, 2, 3, 5]], [1.5, array[4, 3, 2, 1]], ...]`

I want to compare each array and identify the amount of overlap between them. In the above example, that would mean identifying [[1, array[1, **2, 3,** 4]], [0.5, array[2, **2, 3,** 5], ...]]. I care about overlapping values and position.

If more than some threshold (say 1/3) overlap, I want to eliminate the value with the lower coefficient from the dataset. In the above example, this would be the second array with 0.5 instead of 1.

For the above list, the output would be:

```
 [[1, array[1, 2, 3, 4]], [1.5, array[4, 3, 2, 1]], ...]
```

I've managed to pull together a solution (below) but it's very slow. I'm sure there's a better way to approach this, I'm just not sure what it is.

```
survivors = dataset
for i, pair in enumerate(dataset):
        keep_arr = [veto_duplicate(pair, dup) for dup in survivors]
        survivors = list(compress(survivors,keep_arr))
return survivors

def veto_duplicate(path1, path2):
        fractional_overlap = sum(path1[1] == path2[1])/len(path1[1])
        if fractional_overlap > 0.25 and fractional_overlap < 1:
                        if path1[0] < path2[0]:
                                return False
                        else:
                                return True
        else:
                return True
```

If someone could suggest a faster way to do this, I'd be very grateful.

**edit**

All inner arrays are the same size. The final result should contain no arrays which overlap. If there are three (or more) arrays with overlap, I just want to keep the one with the highest coefficient.

Comment: Don't hold your breath.  This isn't the kind of whole-array problem that would have a fast compiled method.

Comment: Are all inner arrays the same size?

Comment: And what if three arrays have pairwise overlap above threshold? How would you like to deal with that situation?

Comment: Hi Ehsan, I've edited the post to answer your questions, but in short: all arrays are the same size, and for N overlapping arrays, I only want the one with the highest coefficient.

Comment: @atalasexpThank you. You can reduce double counting and some operation overhead here, but I am not sure if you can do this in significantly shorter time. I will post a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a somewhat faster solution. Hope it helps:

```
dataset = [[1, np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])], [0.5, np.array([2, 2, 3, 5])], [1.5, np.array([4, 3, 2, 1])]]
#sort dataset by first element
dataset.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])
#unnormalize threshold to reduce division everytime
threshold = 1/3 * len(dataset[0][1])
survivors = dataset.copy()
id_to_del = []
for i, pair in enumerate(dataset):
    for dup in dataset[i+1:]:
        if sum(pair[1]==dup[1])>threshold:
            id_to_del.append(i)
            break

for i in id_to_del:
    del(survivors[i])
#converting to numpy and deleting might be faster if list is too long, but requires reformatting:
#survivors = np.delete(np.array(survivors), id_to_del, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
[[1, array([1, 2, 3, 4])], [1.5, array([4, 3, 2, 1])], ...]
```

Comment: Fantastic, this roughly halves the time when I apply it to my full dataset. Thanks.